# Collatz Conjecture code "bouncing" between 13 and 19

Tags: c

I'm trying to solve problem 14 on project euler, and my initial brute force attempt has me stumped.  For some reason, the code encounters a cycle between 13 and 19.  I don't think I can righteously proceed onto non-brute methods unless I can first get the brute-force method to at least compute correctly.
My code looks like this:

```
unsigned int loop(unsigned int n) 
{
    unsigned int count = 0;
    while(1) 
    {
        while(is_even(n)) 
        {
            n /= 2;
        }
        if(n > 1)
            n = (n * 3) + 1;
        else
            break;
        count++;
        printf("%d,", n);
    }
    printf("%d\n", n);
    return count;
}
```

is_even(n) is computed as "n & 0x01".

Can anyone tell me why the output is a continuous (and theoretically endless) stream of "13,19," repeated?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`n & 0x01` will be `1` if `n` is *odd*, not if it is *even*. Change `is_even` to return `!(n & 0x01)`.

Comment: Thanks, I obviously wasn't paying enough attention when I wrote that function!